# drawing shapes on a grid

Tags: java, java-2d

I need to draw random shapes on a grid such as lines squares etc. This part I'm able to do. My problem is the start and end point of the lines I'm drawing falls anywhere in a grid cell. I would like them to be only at intersection points. One cell in the grid is a 10x10 pixel grid. Do i have to write an algorithm to assign the pixel to its nearest intersection point on the grid or is there a easier way. I'm using a buffered image to draw the grid. Please Help. this is what i have so far

```
for (int i = 0; i < 61; i++) {
                g2d.drawLine((imgDim.width + 2) / 40 * i, 0,
                        (imgDim.width + 2) / 40 * i, imgDim.height - 1);
                g2d.drawLine(0, (imgDim.height + 2) / 60 * i,
                        imgDim.width - 1, (imgDim.height + 2) / 60 * i);
            }
```

Thank you

Comment: Yes, you have to write an algorithm to assign the pixel to its nearest intersection point on the grid before you draw the shape.

Comment: Thank you for the replys can any one give me a start for this kind of algorithm

Answer (score 0):

How are you coming up with the random points?  Making an adjustment there might be the easiest way.  That is, just drop a 0 in the process you are using to come up with the points in the first place.  Then when you are ready to draw it, add a 0 back.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously?  In order to make a random point (pixelX, pixelY) snap to the closest point of a grid.

```
int gridSize = 10;
int x = (pixelX + gridSize / 2) / gridSize * gridSize;
int y = (pixelY + gridSize / 2) / gridSize * gridSize;
```